# CSOM not working for different users. "No credentials are available in the security package" returned

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model, spmetal

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application running. It reads and feeds most of its data from a SharePoint portal (but it is not running as a SP App, but independently).

Since performance is not a critical issue, I am using SPMetal. I set it up to authenticate against Active Directory and allow only users from a group in the domain. An external entity will access this web application and give data to it, and some of the data will be pushed to SharePoint lists (this already works). The web app is running out of SP because the company did not want to allow direct access to its SP portal.

While all of this seems to work just fine for my user, for some reason, when I wanted to use the web app under different user credentials, it gave me an exception. The other user is also a Site Collection administrator and has access to do pretty much anything on SharePoint (it is a farm administrator), so I don't see what permissions I could give to it. Also, I have validated that both accounts are under the same domain group, although that doesn't even seem relevant to the exception, which doesn't happen under the MVC authentication process, but until the CSOM API is called.

The relevant web.config parts are:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
  <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"
            type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider"
            applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
</system.web>
```

The controller that is being called has the following attribute:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"SOMEDOMAIN\SomeGroup")]
public class SomeController : Controller
```

And the relevant part of the exception thrown is:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): No credentials are available in the security package]
   System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(Byte[] incomingBlob, Boolean throwOnError, SecurityStatus& statusCode) +8314127
   System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(String incomingBlob) +91
   System.Net.NegotiateClient.DoAuthenticate(String challenge, WebRequest webRequest, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate) +8326648
   System.Net.NegotiateClient.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest webRequest, ICredentials credentials) +18
   System.Net.AuthenticationManager.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest request, ICredentials credentials) +322
   System.Net.AuthenticationState.AttemptAuthenticate(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest, ICredentials authInfo) +8318858
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmitForAuth() +8319134
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmit(Exception& e, Boolean& disableUpload) +134

[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +8548300
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout) +234

[MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +14507482
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +622
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.IWSTrustContract.Issue(Message message) +0
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst, RequestSecurityTokenResponse& rstr) +180
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst) +82
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForContext(Uri context, Boolean bearerToken, SecurityToken onBehalfOf, SecurityToken actAs, SecurityToken delegateTo, SPRequestSecurityTokenProperties properties) +1992
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForLegacyLoginContext(Uri context) +154
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.InitUserToken(SPRequest request) +3703
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.SPSiteConstructor(SPFarm farm, Guid applicationId, Guid contentDatabaseId, Guid siteId, Guid siteSubscriptionId, SPUrlZone zone, Uri requestUri, String serverRelativeUrl, Boolean hostHeaderIsSiteName, SPUserToken userToken, Boolean appWebRequest, String appHostHeaderRedirectDomain, String appSiteDomainPrefix, String subscriptionName, String appSiteDomainId, Uri primaryUri) +2282
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, SPUserToken userToken) +1515
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean contextSite, SPUserToken userToken) +90
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(String requestUrl) +140
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.Provider.SPServerDataConnection..ctor(String url, Boolean crossSiteCollection) +589
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataContext.get_DataConnection() +124
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.<>c__DisplayClass2`1.<GetList>b__1() +80
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataContext.GetList(String listName, Func`1 getUrl, Func`1 getList, Boolean checkUrl) +426
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataContext.GetList(String listName) +590
   xxxxxxxxxxx.Utilities.SPEntityContextDataContext.get_Factura() in c:\xxxxxxxxx\Utilities\SPEntityContext.cs:52
```

I determined that this was a SharePoint related error since I found the following entries in ULS viewer:

```
11/11/2014 21:54:16.13  iisexpress.exe (0x15F8) 0x1E48  SharePoint Foundation   Claims Authentication   fsq7    High    SPSecurityContext: Request for security token failed with exception: System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No credentials are available in the security package     at System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(Byte[] incomingBlob, Boolean throwOnError, SecurityStatus& statusCode)     at System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(String incomingBlob)     at System.Net.NegotiateClient.DoAuthenticate(String challenge, WebRequest webRequest, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate)     at System.Net.NegotiateClient.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest webRequest, ICredentials credentials)     at System.Net.AuthenticationManager.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest request, ICredentials credentials)     at System.Net.AuthenticationState.AttemptAuthenticate(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest, ICredentials authInfo)     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmitForAuth()     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmit(Exception& e, Boolean& disableUpload)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.IWSTrustContract.Issue(Message message)     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst, RequestSecurityTokenResponse& rstr)     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForContext(Uri context, Boolean bearerToken, SecurityToken onBehalfOf, SecurityToken actAs, SecurityToken delegateTo, SPRequestSecurityTokenProperties properties)  

11/11/2014 21:54:16.13  iisexpress.exe (0x15F8) 0x1E48  SharePoint Foundation   Claims Authentication   8306    Critical    An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'..
```

This code was working before I put the Roles="domain\group" validation and the roleManager in the web.config. Then I removed it and for some reason it still did not work (I have no idea what changes occurred that could provoke this different behavior).

Any ideas?

EDIT: I worked it out last week, but didn't have time to edit it.

It worked whenever I ran VS2013 as an Administrator, so that IISExpress runs with the same privileges. Then both users work just fine. Of course, IIS in production will not run as an admin, so the correct privileges still have to be set on the account for the application pool.

Comment: How do you do authenticate your request to SP?

Comment: I did no configuration regarding authentication against SP. As far as I am aware, the request is done under the process's user (so the SP web service takes the IIS user as the one doing the request), however, since this other user is not working, I guess my awareness is wrong.

Comment: It looks like you are using NTLM for authentication. This protocol does not support double hopping. Meaning that after you authenticate with you first web app, this web app cannot use your credentials to authenticate against the next hop which would be the SP servers CSOM. You will need to provide the credentials to use for the second hop or change authentication protocol.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2010/05/09/double-hop-authentication-why-ntlm-fails-and-kerberos-works.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx

Comment: I actually got this "fixed" (will edit it in the question in a moment). What you're talking about, the double hopping, is not the desired behavior. User should authenticate against the web app, but the web app's identity is the one that should make the web service call. So, say web app runs on app pool with user WebAppUser, I want SharePoint to always think WebAppUser is the one making the calls. I don't want it to think User A or B (who use the web app) are doing it themselves.